# LINQ| How to transform only the first letter to lowercase

Tags: linq

Using LINQ how can I transform only the first letter of `s.Password` to lowercase

`if (s.Password == password){}`

i want that the first char of `s.Password` will be in lower case,
i tried :

`if( s.Password[0].toString().toLower() + s.Password(1) ) == password ){}`

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to make a decision based on an item's position in LINQ, you can use `Select` that takes a `Func` with two parameters - the item and its index:

```
var pwd = "BadPassword";
var res = new string(
    pwd.Select((c, i) => i==0 ? char.ToLower(c) : c).ToArray()
); // produces badPassword
```

The functor above converts the initial character at `i==0` to lower case, while leaving all other characters in place.

[Demo 1.](http://ideone.com/jVDA5s)

**Note:** LINQ is not necessary for this conversion. You can do the same thing in one line by using `Substring`:

```
var res = char.ToLower(pwd[0]) + pwd.Substring(1);
```

[Demo 2.](http://ideone.com/kopEsn)

Comment: I didnt explain myself well, this is my query:`if (dc.Studios.Any(s => s.Email.Equals(model.UserName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && s.Password == passFirstChLower))` and i want `s.Password` first letter to be lower case\

Comment: @user2487126 Do you want to make a character lowercase, or do you want to check if the character is lowercase? If you need to check lowercase, use `char.IsLower(password[0])`